# Sort by Month in dropdown in power bi

Tags: sorting, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I drag slicer and add Month_paid field in that and convert that one to dropdown 
now month looks like

Feb , aPRIL , June , Jan , Dec

i want to sort these months in dropdown how i should do this

this is the link of sample file

https://www.dropbox.com/s/sp9zfyq2sccgmmi/Claims_test_model_2.pbix?dl=0

will you please check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a "sorting" calculated column by using the following DAX (or something similar):

```
Month Sort = 
MONTH(Claims_excel[CLM_LOSS_DT])
```

Once this has been created, right click on the `Claims_excel[CLM_LOSS_MONTH]` and click the 'Sort by' option and choose the new column.

This will produce the following results:

[image]

If you have actual dates in your field then create a calculated column using the following logic:

```
YearMonthSort = YEAR(Claims_excel[CLM_LOSS_DT])*100 + MONTH(Claims_excel[CLM_LOSS_DT])
```

Comment: this is not possible because there is also many years like from 1900 till now so  could i index each one ?

Comment: If your month paid field only contains month names like you've displayed in your post then this will work. If it is a date then you will need to create another index, please see my edited solution.

Comment: this is the link of sample file https://www.dropbox.com/s/sp9zfyq2sccgmmi/Claims_test_model_2.pbix?dl=0  will you please check ?

Comment: but here you create index manullay like if i have 20 + years then this is not possible to write 20 lines for each year..

Comment: when i try you expression then date column is not coming up in list.. check this image .. https://imgur.com/7Wj0Wyc

Comment: that is because you are trying to create a measure, you need to ensure you are in the table view for that table, right click on a column and select the 'Add Column' option. Then, use the DAX I provided which does not include a calculate. Month Sort = 
MONTH(Claims_excel[CLM_LOSS_DT])

Answer (score 0):

You will need another integer column in that table with numbers 1 to 12 representing the order of the Months. You can create that column in either DAX or M. When created, just select the Month column and click on 'Sort By Column' option in the Modeling tab and select the integer column which was created.This will sort the order of the months in the slicer.
  If the month data in the column is already in an order starting from January to December then a simple Index column (from 'Add Column' tab in Power Query editor) is enough, else a calculated column which will check the month column value for each row and put the corresponding order number in the newly calculated integer column will be required. Refer this https://radacad.com/sort-by-column-in-power-bi

Comment: this is the link of sample file dropbox.com/s/sp9zfyq2sccgmmi/Claims_test_model_2.pbix?dl=0 will you please check ?